# Event management in jQuery (Mobile) single page web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-events

I'm interested in **practical suggestions** and **best practices** for the following **single page web app** case.

1. Is there a better way to handle the events?
2. I've abstracted the ShoppingCart object and used the prototype pattern so I can extend it in the future to use any designated framework like jQuery, underscore, Zepto or whatever. Is there any better way?

I'm using jQuery/jQuery Mobile for a single-page Shopping Cart. Of course the Shopping Cart has multiple pseudo pages which can be injected through AJAX calls. A page mainly consists of a form and some grids. The views are generated server-side.

The main `ShoppingCart` object is abstracted and can work with both jQuery alone or jQuery and jQuery Mobile.

It looks like this:

```
var ShoppingCart = function(){

  // Some general vars.

}

ShoppingCart.prototype.init = function(){

  this.router();

}
```

The `router` method handles the current page events and actions, like binding events or painting certain dynamic HTML elements.

```
ShoppingCart.prototype.router = function(){

  switch(this.currentPageId()){

    case 'productPage':
        this.bindProductQty();
        this.bindProductPricingOptionsElements();
        this.bindOrderButton();
    break;

    case 'checkoutPage':
        this.bindDeleteProduct();
        this.paintStates();
        // [...]
    break;

    // [...]


  }

}
```

Init example with jQuery Mobile:

```
var myShoppingCart = new ShoppingCart();

// Override some of the original methods methods.

myShoppingCart.paintPopup = function( msg, options ) {

    return $.dynamic_popup(msg);

}

myShoppingCart.paintPaymentMethods = function(){

    ShoppingCart.prototype.paintPaymentMethods();

    // Refresh the menu in jQuery Mobile.
    $('#payment').selectmenu('refresh');

}

// [...]

// Init the ShoppingCart using jQuery Mobile
// myShoppingCart.setDebug(true);
myShoppingCart.init();
```

PS: I'm not yet familiar with Node.js or any other derivatives.